# Javascript for loop repeat function problem

Tags: javascript, function, loops

Does anybody know why this code does not create as many elements as I enter in the
`repeat` variable?

It creates only 1 element and not 5, why?

```
function create(el, w, h, bg, repeat){
    for(let i=0; i<repeat; i++){
      el = document.createElement(el);
      el.style.width = w;
      el.style.height = h;
      el.style.background = bg;

      document.body.appendChild(el);
    }
  }

  create("div","100px", "100px", "black", 5);
```

Comment: You're using `el` twice with two different meanings. The second iteration of the loop doesn't like it.

Answer (score 3):

It's because you're overriding the variable `el` that holds the tag. After the first element gets inserted, `el` won't be `"div"` it will be the DOM element that just got inserted. Use different variables:

```
// notice the parameter is renamed from 'el' to 'elTag'

function create(elTag, w, h, bg, repeat) {
    for(let i=0; i<repeat; i++){
      let el = document.createElement(elTag);
      el.style.width = w;
      el.style.height = h;
      el.style.background = bg;

      document.body.appendChild(el);
   }
}
```

Comment: This is a mistake by the OP. It wont help anyone in the future. If you answer, the question can not be deleted anymore. Still i dont understand why they need to downvote.

Comment: @PatrickLüthi There are plenty of these questions these days.

Comment: I know but it is not what stackoverflow is there for. It should be a question a lot of users can get a solution from and not just the OP.

Comment: @PatrickLüthi then should we vote to close as typo, in your opinion? I mean, closing is for avoiding people answering less than useful question, but none of the reasons in the close popup seem to match this one.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca you probalby know more about this than I do. It is just what i picked up from helping here. Most important thing is OP has his solution. But i dont think that there will be a lot or anyone that can solve a problem in the future cause of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `el` to `createElement` every time which is global variable in this case. in the next calls, `el` won't be a 'div' any more. can be solved by declaring local variables with different name than the parameter.

```js
function create(tagName, w, h, bg, repeat){
    for(let i=0; i<repeat; i++){
      const text = document.createTextNode('Node number ' + i);
      const el = document.createElement(tagName);
      el.style.width = w;
      el.style.height = h;
      el.style.background = bg;
      el.style.color = 'white';
      el.appendChild(text);

      document.body.appendChild(el);
    }
  }

  create("div","100px", "100px", "black", 5);
```